# How to utilize the features available in the train data but not in the test data to train the algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I have recently worked on some kaggle competitions  and found some of them provided some features only for the training data but not for the test. For example this [Expedia](https://www.kaggle.com/c/expedia-hotel-recommendations) one does not have session info for test data but for training data. I  can't train the model directly with these features that the test data don't have.

I am wondering what is the best way to leverage these features to improve the model performance? Is there a specific algorithm to deal with these problems?